# using airpods to listen to online meetings

Tags: sound, pipewire

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 23.04.  I am using pipewire and pipewire-pulse. I've successfully paired my AirPods and can hear through them fine.  (I don't think the mic works, but that's not a concern right now as I have another microphone.) When I start an online meeting (Google Meet or Zoom) the sound quality through the AirPods drops, and sounds like the sample rate of the audio has dropped to something like 8000 Hz or so. Any system audio I play while the meeting is running is also low. The quality of the system audio goes up once I close the meeting. All audio is fine through speakers so it seems to be something specifically to do with listening via AirPods. Does anyone have any ideas how I can diagnose - or more importantly fix - the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have fixed it for me: in pavucontrol go to the "Configuration" tab, find the AirPods control and change the profile setting to "High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink, Codec SBC)" for example.